# Почему объявление using вводит не тот метод базового класса, который указан

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class A {
public:
virtual void print()const {
std::cout << "from A" << std::endl;
}
};

class B : public A {
public:
void print()const override{
std::cout << "from B" << std::endl;
}
};

class C : public A {
public:
void print()const override{
std::cout << "from C" << std::endl;
}
};

class D :public B, public C {
public:
using C::print;
};

int main()
{
D d{};
d.print(); //from B
return 0;
}
```

И почему нельзя использовать объявление using при виртуальном наследовании?

Comment: В вашем примере нет виртуального наследования. И [выводится "from C"](https://wandbox.org/permlink/SuwifhRfcax7ksPz). И ничего не нельзя.

Comment: странно у меня в vs2017 выводится from B, а насчет виртуального наследования, его тут нет, но если было бы, using бы не сработало

Comment: Хмм, действительно. Похоже на баг в компиляторе. Что касается виртуального наследования, то в этой ситуации класс `D` должен будет сам реализовать функцию `print` так как именно он будет непосредственно наследовать и инициализировать экземпляр класса `A`. Директива `using` влияет только на обнаружение имен, она не позволяет добавлять реализацию методов в класс.

Comment: Во-первых, проблема не воспроизводится. Во-вторых, что означают странные фразы "нельзя использовать объявление using при виртуальном наследовании", "если было бы [виртуальное наследование], using бы не сработало"? Откуда вы такое взяли? Если бы класс `A` наследовался виртуально, то в коде бы была ошибка об отсутствии final overrider в `D`, которая к `using` вообще никаким боком не относится.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если речь идет о Visual Studio, то это, по-видимому, баг компилятора.

Кодогенератор Visual Studio по какой-то причине принимает решение в такой ситуации реализовать вызов `d.print()` как полноценный виртуальный вызов через таблицу виртуальных функций класса `D`. (В этом, кстати, пока еще нет никакой ошибки.) Но для разрешения этого виртуального вызова он безусловно берет *первую* таблицу в объекте типа `D` (из первой базы в списке баз), по каковой причине такие виртуальные вызовы все время попадают в `B::print`. Если поменять местами базы в объявлении класса `D`, то вызываться все время будет `C::print`.

Если сделать функцию `print` невиртуальной, то проблема пропадает. Если явно сделать вызов невиртуальным, т.е. вместо `d.print()` вызывать `d.D::print()`, то проблема пропадает.

---

Это вообще-то интересная тема. Вызов `d.print()` - это с точки зрения языка виртуальный вызов и разрешаться он должен на основе динамического типа объекта `d`. Т.е. final overrider должен быть взят из класса `D`. А кто является final overrider в `D`? (Точнее, из какой цепочки баз он должен выбираться: `A->B->D` или `A->С->D`?). Using-declaration не может быть использована для разрешения этого вопроса. В стандарте есть показательный пример на эту тему

```
struct A {
  virtual void f();
};

struct B : virtual A {
  virtual void f();
};

struct C : B , virtual A {
  using A::f;
};

void foo() {
  C c;
  c.f();              // calls B​::​f, the final overrider
  c.C::f();           // calls A​::​f because of the using-declaration
}
```

Обратите внимание - `c.f()` должен вызывать `B::f()` несмотря на присутствие `using A::f` в `C`.

По-видимому в нашем примере все начинается c name lookup, который должен использовать using-declaration `using C::print` и локализовать рассмотрение в ветке наследования `A->C`, где final overrider однозначен.

Comment: Если судить по коду из стандарта, тогда в изначальном коде UB. Если `using A::f` не является final overrider, значит и `using C::print;` им не является. Но в таком случае у класса `C` 2 final overriders, что является UB. Но это конечно запутано стандартом, потому что для того, чтобы быть final overrider достаточно объявить сущность, чем, собственно, `using` и занимается.

Comment: Интересно, что в более ранних стандартах была, похоже, такая строчка: _«The rules for member lookup (10.2) are used to determine the final overrider for a virtual function in the scope of a derived class but ignoring names introduced by using-declarations.»_, что многое поясняло. Но этой строчки больше нет.

Comment: [Отчёт об ошибке в MS](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/371839/incorrect-virtual-call-dispatch.html) и небольшое [продолжение темы](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53041293/using-declaration-as-overrider).